# Subfolders inside controllers give 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.10. I am trying to create an admin and user sites separately with the following folder structure

- application

  - controllers

    - admin

      - home.php
    - site

      - home.php

in route.php I have following:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

which I tried changing to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site/home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

It doesn't work.

I want when I go to `http://example.com/site` it should use site/home.php controller and when I go to `http://example.com/admin` it should use admin/home.php controller

As per the official document, when you set a default controller, it should search for the default controller defined in a subfolder, but it does not work.
 https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#directories-and-default-controller-404-override

Many people have fixed it by making changes in the core file of Codeigniter. But I want to do it without making changes in the core files.

Comment: CI will always look for a controller inside the `controllers` folder but as you have shown the structure, your `home.php` lies outside the `controllers` folder.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi I have edited the directory structure as it was not correct earlier because while saving I did not put indent correctly

Answer (score 1):

use in routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

create controller inside admin folder home.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        echo "demo text";       
    }
}
```

Then hit "http://example.com/admin" or "http://example.com/index.php/admin".
if second one url work it means you add .htaccess file application root

Comment: Now I am able to access site from url http://example.com/site and admin section from url http://example.com/admin. 

Now I want is site should be accessible from url http://example.com ('without site in url'). But admin section should be still working on url http://example.com/admin

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use sub_dirs with default controller .. but if you have to do so create a normal route as following:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

And inside home controller you may use redirect to `site/home`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$route['default_controller']` is used for the root address without segments http://example.com/. But you have addresses with segments http://example.com/site and http://example.com/admin.

> I want when I go to http://example.com/site it should use
>   site/home.php controller and when I go to  http://example.com/admin it
>   should use admin/home.php controller

You need to do this in your `routes.php`:

```
$route['site'] = 'site/home';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/home';
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting the default controller for you folder sub-folder to home add the following to your /application/config/routes.php file:

```
$route['folder'] = "folder/home";
```